404 error when trying to connect to the websocket (Angular + Spring boot)
In Angular i tried to connect to the websocket but an error message is returned :
websocket.service.ts:15 GET http://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OxuZ1WH 404 (Not Found)
this is my code :
for the SpringBoot :
WebSocketController :@CrossOrigin(origins ="*")
@RestController
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketController {

    @Autowired
    private FutureService futureService;

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private FutureAlertRepository futureAlertRepository;
    
    
     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
     //@GetMapping("/futuresget") 
        public ResponseEntity<List<List<Map<String, Object>>>> fetchFutures() {
            List<List<Map<String, Object>>> futures = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(futures);
        }
     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
        //@GetMapping("/futuress") 
        public void sendUpdates() {
            List<List<Map<String, Object>>> updatedData = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/futures", updatedData);
            futureService.updateDatabase(updatedData); 
       }

FutureHandler :
@Component
 public class FutureHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

     @Autowired
     private FutureService futureService;

     @Override
     protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException {

         try {
             if (message.getPayload().equals("testFetchFutures")) {
                 List<List<Map<String, Object>>> futures = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
                 String jsonData = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(futures); 
                 session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(jsonData));
             } else if (message.getPayload().equals("testSendUpdates")) {
                 sendUpdates();
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Error sending data: " + e.getMessage()));
         } catch (Exception e) {
             session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Error processing message: " + e.getMessage()));
         }
     }

     public void sendUpdates() {
         List<List<Map<String, Object>>> updatedData = futureService.fetchDataFromApi();
         futureService.updateDatabase(updatedData); 
     }
 }

WebSocketConfig :

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebSocket
@CrossOrigin(origins ="*")
public class WebSocketConfig implements  WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); 
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS();
    }
     
        
    @Bean
    FutureHandler customFutureHandler() {
        return new FutureHandler();
    }
}

Pom.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
              <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
               <version>3.4.1</version>
         </dependency>
         
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

And now for the Angular :
WebSocket service :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Socket, io } from 'socket.io-client';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class WebsocketService {
private socket: Socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io('ws://localhost:8081/users/websocket');

  }

  connect(): void {
    this.socket.connect();
  }

  disconnect(): void {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }

  sendTestFetchFutures(): void {
    this.socket.emit('testFetchFutures');
  }

  sendTestSendUpdates(): void {
    this.socket.emit('testSendUpdates');
  }

  listenForUpdates(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('updates', (data: any) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
    });
  }


}

And for my Component :
export class FuturesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  pageSize = 13;
  currentPage = 1;

  futures: Futures[] = [];

  sortedColumn: string | null = null;
  sortAscending: boolean | null = null;
  originalData: Futures[] = [];

  mode: 'USD' | 'Notional' = 'USD';

  showFilterForm: boolean = false;

  private refreshSubscription!: Subscription;

  latestFuture: Futures | null = null;
  subscription: Subscription | null = null;
  private updatesSubscription!: Subscription;
  messages: string[] = [];
  error: any = null;
  constructor(private globalDataTableService: GlobalDataTableService, private router: Router,private websocketService: WebsocketService) {}
  ngOnInit() {

    this.globalDataTableService.getFutures().subscribe((data) => {
      this.futures = data;
      this.originalData = [...data];
    });

    this.updatesSubscription = this.websocketService.listenForUpdates().subscribe((data: Futures[]) => {
      this.futures = data;
      this.originalData = [...data];
    });

    this.refreshSubscription = interval(60000).subscribe(() => {
      this.refreshData();
    });
  }
  refreshData() {
    this.globalDataTableService.getFutures().subscribe((data) => {
      this.futures = data;
      this.originalData = [...data];
    });
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.refreshSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.updatesSubscription.unsubscribe();
 
  }}

I really cannot understand what's wrong with my code, so I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.
